# How to execute JMeter test case from Java code

Tags: eclipse, jmeter, java-7

How do I run a JMeter test case from Java code?

I have followed the example [Here](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)  from Blazemeter.com

My code is as follows:

```
public class BasicSampler {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    // JMeter Engine
    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

    // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/home/stone/Workbench/automated-testing/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/home/stone/Workbench/automated-testing/apache-jmeter-2.11");
    JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();

    // Initialize JMeter SaveService
    SaveService.loadProperties();

    // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/home/stone/Workbench/automated-testing/apache-jmeter-2.11/bin/examples/CSVSample.jmx");
    HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
    in.close();

    // Run JMeter Test
    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();
}
```

}

but I keep getting the following messages in the console and my test never executes.

> INFO    2014-09-23 12:04:40.492 [jmeter.e] (): Listeners will be started after enabling running version
>   INFO    2014-09-23 12:04:40.511 [jmeter.e] (): To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false

I have also tried uncommented jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false from jmeter.properties file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How do you know that your "test never executes"?
2. What is in `jmeter.log` file (it should be in the root of your project). Or alternatively comment `JMeterUtils.initLogging()` line to see the full output in STDOUT
3. Have you changed relative path `CSVSample_user.csv` in "Get user details" CSV Data Set Config as it may resolve into a different location as it recommended in [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)
4. Is `CSVSample.jtl` file generated anywhere (again it should be in the root of your project by default)? What is in it?

The code looks good and I'm pretty sure that the problem is with the path to `CSVSample_user.csv` file and you have something like `java.io.FileNotFoundException` in your log. Please double check that CSVSample.jmx file contains **valid full path** to CSVSample_user.csv.

**UPDATE TO ANSWER QUESTIONS IN COMMENTS**

1. `jmeter.log` file should be under your Eclipse workspace folder by default
2. Looking into `CSVSample.jmx` there is a `View Resulst in Table` listener which is configured to store results under `~/CSVSample.jtl`
3. If you want to see summarizer messages and "classic" .jtl reporting add next few lines before `jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);` stanza

   ```
   Summariser summer = null;
   String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
   if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
       summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
   }

   String logFile = "/path/to/jtl/results/file.jtl";
   ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
   logger.setFilename(logFile);
   testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
   ```

Comment: Thank you, it was as you suspected,java.io.FileNotFoundException it was looking for CSV files in Eclipse's workspace, project folder. the problem is that the jmeter.log is not created, I was able to see the log once commented out JMeterUtils.initLogging() line.

Comment: How can I ensure that the jmeter.log is created? 

Where are the results stored? I cannot see a .jtl file

Answer (score 1):

Try using library - https://github.com/abstracta/jmeter-java-dsl.

It supports implementing JMeter test as java code.

Below example shows how to implement and execute test for REST API. Same approach could be applied to other type of tests as well.

```java
  @Test
  public void testPerformance() throws IOException {
    TestPlanStats stats = testPlan(
      threadGroup(2, 10,
        httpSampler("http://my.service")
          .post("{\"name\": \"test\"}", Type.APPLICATION_JSON)
      ),
      //this is just to log details of each request stats
      jtlWriter("test" + Instant.now().toString().replace(":", "-") + ".jtl")
    ).run();
    assertThat(stats.overall().elapsedTimePercentile99()).isLessThan(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
  }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for better understanding.